# How can I grant a user the option CREATE DATABASE in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want that a user can create a database, but when I execute this:

```sql
GRANT CREATE DATABASE TO rmedrano
```

I get this error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission can only be granted in the master database.

How can I do this?

Comment: `USE Master` first?

Comment: For `CREATE DATABASE` the user must also be a user in `master`.  If you don't want this then grant `CREATE ANY DATABASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Members of the dbcreator fixed server role can create, alter, drop,
> and restore any database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15